# C - reading from file

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

I'm trying to write a program,in which after pressing the 'v' button on the keyboard it opens a file for reading, and after pressing 'k' it closes the file and also ends the program.
(There will be more functions in the program, which will individually use the opened file, so it needs to remain open [I know it's a dumb way to design the program, but it's a homework with these rules]).
However, if I want to close the program in the same function `main` it was opened, but not in the same place, it gives me an error messagae `fclose(fr)-fr is not unidentified`
Can anyone help me?

Here is my code :

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    while(1){
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if(c == 'v'){
            FILE *fr;
            fr = fopen("D:\\Programming\\C\\Projekt\\Projekt 1\\pacienti.txt","r");            
            v();
        }
        else if(c == 'k'){
            fclose(fr);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The typos make your post hard to read. Please review and [edit] to fix.

Comment: Why don't you use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/)? Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). See also [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: `FILE *fr;` must be moved before the `while`loop. Probably *v* needs to get *fr* in arg ?

Comment: Please copy&paste the full error message.

Comment: `fr` is not identified because its not in scope of `else if`

Comment: OT: don't use fancy names like `v` but use meaningful names.$

Answer (score 2):

> (fclose(fr)-fr is not unidentified

your code cannot compile because

> ```
> fclose(fr);
> ```

use the unknown variable *fr*

To be able to close the previously opened file you need to move `FILE *fr;` before the `while` loop, allowing it to be usable in the two branches of the `if`.

I also encourage you to initialize that variable with *NULL* to avoid undefined behavior if the input *k* is used before the input *v*. A proper way is also to test it is not *NULL* before to call `fclose` and to set it to *NULL* after closing the file.

Anyway *fr* is only internal to *mail* and to open the file seems useless, what the function *v* is doing ?

Out of that very probably you want to replace

> ```
> scanf("%c",&c);
> ```

by

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

to bypass spaces including newline, or better to also check `scanf` returns 1 to manage EOF case, for instance if `stdin` redirected to a file.

Note if successive *v* without *k* are input you open the file several times without closing it.

Comment: Calling `fclose` on NULL is also UB.

Comment: Actually `fr` should be initialized to NULL and it should be `if (fr) {free(fr); fr = NULL;}`. And `fr` should not be fopened again if it is already open. TBO the requirement is really strange.

Comment: without initializing the var its value is undefined so UB,*fclose* waits for a pointer, difficult to imagine to receive NULL in arg is UB for *fclose*

Comment: @Jabberwocky `if (fr) {fclose(fr); fr = NULL;}` agree this is the best way, I edit my answer